# How to enable/disable MenuItem based on change in class variable

Tags: android, android-menu

I have an options menu in an `Activity` with three `MenuItems`

- create
- select
- delete

When there is no item currently selected I disable the `MenuItem` for delete.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic_menu, menu);
    this.deleteCharMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.basic_menu_deletechar);
    this.deleteCharMenu.setEnabled(this.current != null);
    return true;
}
```

However `onCreateOptionsMenu` is not called every time the menu is opened (try and error got me this result).

So I stored the `MenuItem` in a class variable to be able to change its state whenever `this.current` changed its value.

Is there a more elegant method to ensure that the correct `MenuItems` are enabled and disabled? I am hoping for some kind of listener I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

overload the onPrepareMenu , it is called right before it's shown.

Comment: thanks so much. teaches me to look at all the methods in Activity more closely in the future.